# How can I use Transaction in EF in ASP.NET MVC 5 Clean architecture?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I have read the Clean Architecture Document and eShopOnWeb of Mr. Ardalis and implemented them in my project, ASP.NET MVC5.
Also, I have implemented IUnitOfWork.

I have three layers in my project

1. ApplicationCore
2. Infrastructure
3. UI

In `ApplicationCore` I have a repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    List<TEntity> GetAll(ISpecification<TEntity> specification = null);
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

and an `IUnitOfWork` interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void BeginTransaction();
    IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    void Commit();
    void TransactionCommit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

In the `Infrastructure` layer, I have Implement of these interfaces:

```
public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly OrderExchangeEntities _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    public EfRepository(OrderExchangeEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAll(ISpecification<TEntity> specification = null)
    {
        if (specification != null)
        {
            return _entities.Where(specification.Criteria).ToList();
        }

        return _entities.ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return _entities.Find(id);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _entities.Attach(entity);
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _entities.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }
}
```

Implementation of `IUnitOfWork`:

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly OrderExchangeEntities _dbContext;
    private IDbTransaction _transaction;

    public EFUnitOfWork(OrderExchangeEntities dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = _dbContext.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return new EfRepository<TEntity>(_dbContext);
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        _transaction?.Rollback();
    }

    public void TransactionCommit()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction?.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            _transaction?.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use this begin transaction in `OrderPaymentService` ?

```
public class OrderPaymentMessageService : IOrderPaymentMessageService
{
private readonly IRepository<OrderPaymentMessage> _orderPaymentMessageRepository;
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private readonly IAppLogger _applogger;
private readonly IOrderService _orderServices;

public OrderPaymentMessageService(IRepository<OrderPaymentMessage> orderPaymentMessageRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IAppLogger applogger, IOrderService   orderServices)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _orderPaymentMessageRepository = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<OrderPaymentMessage>();
    _applogger = applogger;
    _orderServices = orderServices;
}

        public bool Create(OrderPaymentMessage orderPaymentMessage)
    {
        _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

        try
            {


            Guard.Against.Null(orderPaymentMessage, nameof(orderPaymentMessage));
                
     _orderPaymentMessageRepository.Add(orderPaymentMessage);
    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

     var documwentsList=_userDocumentsService.GetAllDocumentsByOrderID(orderPaymentMessage.OrderID.GetValueOrDefault()).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

             bool isSucces=   _userDocumentsService.DeleteRange(documwentsList);
             bool isSend=   _orderServices.MarkAdminSendPaymentMessage(1, 1,DateTime.Now);
            
        if (isSend)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Commit();
                return true;
            }
           else
            {
                _unitOfWork.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
           
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            _unitOfWork.Rollback();
                _applogger.LogError(ex);
                return false;
            }
        

           
        
       
    }

public List<OrderPaymentMessageModel> GetMessageByOrderID(int orderID)
{
    try
    {
        Guard.Against.Zero(orderID, nameof(orderID));
        var query =new  GetOrderPaymentMessageByOrderID(orderID);
        return _orderPaymentMessageRepository.GetAll(query).Select(x => new
           OrderPaymentMessageModel
        {
            OrderID = x.OrderID,
            ID = x.ID,
            Message = x.Message,
            CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
        }
           ).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _applogger.LogError(ex);
        return null;
    }
}


public List<OrderPaymentMessageModel> GetMessageByOrderID(int orderID)
{
    try
    {
        Guard.Against.Zero(orderID, nameof(orderID));
        var query =new  GetOrderPaymentMessageByOrderID(orderID);
        return _orderPaymentMessageRepository.GetAll(query).Select(x => new
           OrderPaymentMessageModel
        {
            OrderID = x.OrderID,
            ID = x.ID,
            Message = x.Message,
            CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
        }
           ).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _applogger.LogError(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I want to use Begin transaction in `OrderPaymentMessageService` to create record and update Order Record using transaction.If the record has not been updated, it will rollback.

Comment: So why dont you use `BeginTransaction()`? What happens when you do?

Comment: @mxmissile `BeginTransaction()` yes,I have implemented it in my code, but it's not working.

Comment: Your code doesn't show that, and what does "not working" mean? It looks like you included all of the code except the most important parts.

Comment: @ssmith sir check my code again i updated code

Comment: Define "not working". What exactly do you mean? Are you getting errors? What happens when you use your debugger?

Comment: It looks like it should be working, at least at a cursory level. So again, what behavior or errors are you seeing?